# Discord.py Userinfo

Tags: python, discord

I have wrote this userinfo code:

```
@bot.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member, roles=None, author=None):
    if member:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Userinfo für {member.name}",
                              description=f"Dies ist eine Userinfo für den User {member.mention}")
        embed.add_field(name="Server beigetreten:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y, %H:%M:%S"))
        embed.add_field(name="Discord beigetreten:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y, %H:%M:%S"))
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

and i want to code that if someone types "+userinfo" without a member provided it shows them their own userinfo and i tried some things but havent gotten any good results

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, roles=None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Userinfo für {member.name}", description=f"Dies ist eine Userinfo für den User {member.mention}")
        embed.add_field(name="Server beigetreten:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y, %H:%M:%S"))
        embed.add_field(name="Discord beigetreten:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y, %H:%M:%S"))
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).